# Only notifications from text messages are being shown

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4, push-notifications

As the title says, I only get notifications from my texting application but not from everything else.

A couple of examples:

- I use pushbullet to share a website with my phone, but I won't get the notification until I open the app.
- To see if I have to  manually open the app and refresh it, same thing with emails.
- If I install an app on my device remotely from the play store, the app won't start downloading/installing till I open the play store on my phone.
- Texting works as expected, i get notifications normally even with my third party texting app. (textra)

Specs:

- Samsung Galaxy S4
- SGH-i337M
- 5.0.1
- Nova Launcher (if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've gone into the developer options and turned on "limit background processes", which stops apps running in the background to do all these things. The fact that they work normally when you open the app by hand suggests that app is still getting the information it needs, just not until it's in the foreground. The fact it's the whole behaviour of the app (e.g. Play Store downloading updates), not just the appearance of the notification tells me it's not just a problem with notifications.

Comment: I just checked and i didn't have them unlocked, so i did the tap thing to get them then dissabled them